# 'Invalid Date error' appears when trying to find difference between fromTime and toTime

Tags: html, typescript, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have two ionic date-time pickers (fromTime and toTime), and a method to calculate the time difference between them. The same method works when I use date values but not when I use time as I keep getting and 'Invalid Date' error message.

I've tried a few different suggestions for calculating the time but nothing has worked yet, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The HTML:

```
 <ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-datetime class="timeBtn" displayFormat="HH:mm" pickerFormat="HH:mm" minuteValues="00,30" [(ngModel)]="fromTime" (ngModelChange)="timeChange($event, 'fromTime' )" (click)="calculateHours()" placeholder="Select Start Time"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col><ion-icon class="center" name="arrow-round-forward"></ion-icon></ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-datetime class="timeBtn" displayFormat="HH:mm" pickerFormat="HH:mm" minuteValues="00,30" [(ngModel)]="toTime" (ngModelChange)="timeChange($event, 'toTime' )" (click)="calculateHours()" placeholder="Select End Time"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>

<ion-label class="number">{{hoursStr}}</ion-label>  
<ion-label class="center">Total Hours</ion-label>
```

The TS:

```
 public fromTime;
 public toTime;  

 constructor(....
 ) {

    let date = new Date();
this.fromTime = date.getHours() + "-" + date.getMinutes();
this.toTime = date.getHours() + "-" + date.getMinutes();

}

  timeChange(e, dateName) {

    this.request[dateName] = new Date(e);
}

  getTime(fromTime, toTime) {
    var start = moment(fromTime);
    var end = moment(toTime);
    var ms = moment(end, "HH:mm").diff(moment(start, " HH:mm"));
    var d = moment.duration(ms);
    var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":");
    var t = parseFloat(s);
    return t;
}

   hoursStr = "";
calculateHours() {
    console.log("firedTime", this.fromTime, this.toTime)
    if (this.fromTime && this.toTime) {
        this.hoursStr = "" + this.getTime(this.fromTime, this.toTime)
    }
    console.log(this.hoursStr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
moment.duration(this.start.diff(end)).as("minutes")
```

too many conversions in ur code: u can work with moment objects an convert them to the format u need when u need it; otherwise the risk is to get unknown formats as inputs

Comment: ..did u try it?

Comment: Hi, Thank you. Yes i tried this but i did not work.
The error was because of the type of value i defined in my model (integer not float)